# Laravel Seed db:seed [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Fatal error: Class 'model' not found

Tags: symfony, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I 'm taking the FactoryModel Tool to populate the database for THIS Do the following :

Create Table :

```
Php artisan make:model “Users” –m
```

Up mysql :

```
php artisan migrate
```

migrate:

```
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password',60);
        $table->enum('type',['Miembro','Administrador'])->default('Miembro');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
}
```

Model Users

```
{
 use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword; 

 protected $table = 'users'; 

 protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password','type']; 

protected $hidden = [
'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

in ModelFactory.php;

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
'name' => $faker->name,
'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
'password' => bcrypt('123'),
'type' => 'administrador',
'remember_token' => str_random(10),
];

});
```

in dataseSeeder.php:

```
 public function run()
{
model::unguard();

factory('App\User','Administrador',3)->create();

model::reguard();
```

}

migrate BD :

```
  php artisan db:seed
```

ERROR:
    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
    Fatal error: Class 'model' not found

I appreciate your help

DGR

Comment: Hi try `Model::unguard();` and `Model::reguard();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model class name should be "User" and not "Users".
Then the name of the factory definition is not set in ModelFactory.php, it should look like:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, 'Administrador', function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
    'password' => bcrypt('123'),
    'type' => 'administrador',
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
});
```